# how to implement application update for android Apps

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, updating

The way I develop android apps is, by Making an App with Sencha Touch ExtJS, then I use Eclipse like we normally do for android app development and just package my already build Sencha Touch ExtJS app. And i get an APK.

Now what i want is, when the app load it should check from a predefined server whether there is a newer version of the app available, if yes then download it and update the installed app.

How to implement it. I am new to Sencha and Android Packaging so please explain to me like, i am a dummy.